# Using Angular for data entry in a table

Tags: angularjs

[image: Data Entry Screen]

We're building a new time entry system that uses legacy data. I've attached a screen that shows the UI.

```
 `Here's a link to a fiddle with some mostly working code.' 


http://jsfiddle.net/dgdavidson/GMUK5/3/
```

As you can see, we have a row of data that contains a weeks worth of time entries and comments for each entry.

Problems now include getting data to update. For example, clicking 'New Entry' or the delete button doesn't update the table until those buttons are clicked a second time. Do we have to force an update?

For a change to time entries hours or comments, because the data is in an object inside of an object how do we capture the change? It seems we need the $index for the row as well as the $index for the date we're changing.

Something we haven't even started on yet is another row underneath the total hours row that will be dropdowns so that the user can enter the location they were at for that days work.

We feel that Angular is a good choice for what we are doing so I suppose my biggest question is are we going in the right direction with this or do we have a fundamental architectural issue?

Comment: You should follow the rules. The reason you cannot post a fiddle link is because you should *include relevant code* here.

Comment: You're using jQuery inside your controllers, which is bad practice. If you want to capture the change, you should add a watcher.

Comment: Well I'd love to but SO says that my relevant code is too long which I kind of knew which is why I didn't include it here.

Comment: So instead of $scope.newEntry I should use something like `$scope.$watchCollection('entries', function(new, old) {
 // save the data
          });`